# How to install gattlib in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, raspberrypi

I compiled, built and packaged GATTLIB library files in Raspberry Pi 3 as directed in https://github.com/labapart/gattlib. But when trying to install the library from the build folder (`/home/pi/Downloads/gattlib-src-root/gattlib-master/build`) by using

```
sudo apt-get install gattlib
```

I got error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gattlib
```

Please advise me what is the correct way to install GATTLIB in Raspberry pi 3.

Comment: Apt-get installs packages from repositories, and knows nothing about "build folder". Assuming you've built a .deb package, use `sudo dpkg -i pkg-name.deb` to install it.

Comment: Thanks. The correct command  was:                                                                                                     $ sudo dpkg -i gattlib_0.2-dev_armhf.deb

Comment: The installation (depackaging) went without errors but now I cannot locate the installed files: gattlib.h and libgattlib.so. According to the link above I set the installation path as:                                        cpack -DCPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=/usr/local .. and indeed the CPackSourceConfig.cmake shows it correctly (SET(CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
but where are the installed files? I cannot locate them anywhere in the /usr folder. Please advise me.

Comment: Now I found that gatlib.h file was installed into /usr/include folder and libgattlib.so file into /usr/lib folder. So the dpkg command did not heed the installation package settings.

Comment: I have also a different problem related to libgatlib.so location. When building my VC++ project, the linker complains that: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgattlib". But the libgattlib.so path is correctly set. Please advise me what should be the problem.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) based on @mikewhatever's comment and OP's response.

Comment: Thank you David. Yes, this link also helped me. I have a new question regarding using gattlib in VS2017 VC++ for Linux project for Raspbian on Raspberry Pi3. Here is the link to "How to link libgattlib.so in a VS2017 VC++ for Linux project": https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026726/how-to-link-libgattlib-so-in-a-vs2017-vc-for-linux-project. I was not able to find a useful clue on the net.

Comment: Setting:

1- \\<Board IP Address>\usr\lib into Project->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories
2- gattlib into  Project->Configuration Properties->->Linker->Input
3- -lpthread to Project->Configuration Properties->Linker->Command Line                                                                                               
 
solved the problem with referencing a remote .so library in a VS 2017 VC++ for Linux project.
Hopefully this summary will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution on this link worked for me on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Gattlib with Python 3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721463/cant-install-gattlib-on-rasperry-pi-error-stray-xxx-in-program-on-usr-incl

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.