# How to link libgattlib.so in a VS2017 VC++ for Linux project

Tags: compiling, c++, raspberrypi, arm

I tried to build a VC++ for Linux (Raspbian) project in VS2017 (from my PC)using libgattlib.so static library residing in Raspberry Pi 3 board. The compilation went without errors. I can reliably include in the project .h files using e.g. **\\usr\include**. I also need a reference to the libgattlib.so library file. It resides in /usr/lib on the Raspberry Pi 3 and the link is correctly(**\\usr\lib**) set in VS2017 **Project->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories** and **-lgattlib** in **Project->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Library Dependencies** but the linker reports error:

Target Link:

```
1>  Linking objects    
1>  Invoking 'ld'    
1>  g++ -o "/home/pi/projects/Id2Monitor_For_Linux/bin/ARM/Debug/Id2Monitor_For_Linux.out" -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack /home/pi/projects/Id2Monitor_For_Linux/obj/ARM/Debug/main.o -lbluetooth -llibgattlib    
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgattlib    
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgattlib    
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
1>  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgattlib    
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
1>  collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status    
1>  Done linking, output file name: '/home/pi/projects/Id2Monitor_For_Linux/bin/ARM/Debug/Id2Monitor_For_Linux.out'    
1>Done building target "Link" in project "Id2Monitor_For_Linux.vcxproj" -- FAILED.    
1>    
1>Done building project "Id2Monitor_For_Linux.vcxproj" -- FAILED.    
1>    
1>Build FAILED.    
1>    
1>collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status    
1>    0 Warning(s)    
1>    1 Error(s)
```

Please advise me how to correctly set up the references for libgattlib.so library in VS2017. Thanks.

Comment: Setting:

1- \\<Board IP Address>\usr\lib into Project->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories
2- gattlib into  Project->Configuration Properties->->Linker->Input
3- -lpthread to Project->Configuration Properties->Linker->Command 
 
solved the problem with rreferencing a remote .so library in a VS 2017 VC++ for Linux project.

Hopefully this summary will help somebody else.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you very much. It helped to solve my problem in Visual Studio 2017 with Linux remote compiler. Where I've needed to include Linux libraries I've had __float128 error and was stuck. I've done the following:

1. Copied `/usr/include` from Linux machine into Windows.
2. `D:\usr\include` into Project -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories
3. The library that I wanted to use for my project was portaudio so I added portaudio into Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies
4. -lportaudio -lrt -lpthread to Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line